# Rubocop custom cop nodepattern class method regardless class/modules

Tags: ruby, rubocop, rubocop-nodepattern

I would like to catch all the `bar` class methods regardless its class/module.

I can catch `Foo.bar` with `(send (const nil? :Foo) :bar)` but i would like to catch `Woohoo::Foo.bar` or even `Woohoo::Foo.bar(some_attr: some_value)`.

I basically want to say `.bar` method is deprecated use `some_new_method` instead.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, instead of forcing the constant's scope to be `nil?`, you can accept any scope with

```
(send (const _ :Foo) :bar)
```

Comment: Thanks! This matches `Any::Thing::Like::Foo.bar` but how can i specify it should match with all the params as well like `bar(1)` or `bar(foo: bar)`

Comment: `(send (const _ :Foo) :bar ...)` did the trick! Thanks a lot Marc!